# Why do I get a two second lag between vsc and it's integrated python terminal on my fairly powerful ubuntu computer?

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

New to linux, but I've been using VSC for over a year now and have never had this problem even on fairly slow laptops.

When I type a simple line of code e.g.

```
a = 5
```

There will be a roughly two second delay between pressing shift + enter and the code running in the terminal. I'm not just talking about when the terminal first opens, the latency persists even after the terminal has been running for a while.

I've tried reinstalling VSCode, and reseting the settings.json file, but it didn't seem to make any difference. I also reinstalled the python extension for VSC but to no avail.

The only extension I am running is the official microsofft python extension.

I do not observe this problem with Jupyter notebook or Spyder

**Specs**:

Intel® Core™ i9-10900 CPU @ 2.80GHz × 20

GeForce RTX 2080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2

Gnome: 3.28.2

OS: 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

RAM: I think 64gb, but it might be 32gb.

Comment: Does this happen with other editors?

Comment: It works flawlessly in Jupyter notebook and Spyder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a solution, so I installed installed VSCodium which is an open-source clone of VSCode. It doesn't have any latency whatsoever and seems to have all the features of VSCode I needed.

To install it, I ran the following code in the terminal.

```
wget -qO - https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/raw/master/pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add - 

echo 'deb https://paulcarroty.gitlab.io/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/debs/ vscodium main' | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscodium.list 

sudo apt update && sudo apt install codium
```

Source of above code and instructions for how to install on other operating systems: https://vscodium.com/